# "Fails to get size of gamma" error when trying to set resolution

Tags: 11.10, resolution

On 11.10 my max allowed resolution is 1024x768, while my monitor supports 1280x800 on windows.

I've seen a method to solve this via xrandr, but I allways get a message saying it fails to get size of gamma.

```
 xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

Is there any other way to add 1280x800 resolution to my laptop, any workarounds this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a modeline in your Xorg.conf file.
Please read this:
http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQVideoModes
The part about powerstrip may be interesting as you have windows running with the correct resolution.

Comment: how do I even find the xorg.conf file ?

Comment: trudat, I can't find it.

Comment: @MaxPayne: /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Answer (score 3):

I noticed your maximum resolution shown in xrandr was limited to 1024x768. Maybe FIRST you may follow the wiki below and try forcing X to recognize the video RAM.

[Not recognised video cards](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Not_recognised_video_cards)

i.e. putting new lines in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-vesahack`.

After the max is successfully changed after a reboot, you may proceed to next steps, for example `--newmode` and `--addmode`, etc.

I happened to have this problem during the debugging of my ivy bridge. I think this might be the reason of your "Failed to get size of gamma" error.

Answer (score 1):

Take a backup of /etc/X11/xorg.conf and add the below lines.it worked for me for OEL6.5

---

```
# VirtualBox generated configuration file
# based on /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

# XFree86 4 configuration created by pyxf86config

# Section "ServerLayout"
#       Identifier     "Default Layout"
#       Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
#       InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
#       InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
# EndSection

Section "Files"

# RgbPath is the location of the RGB database.  Note, this is the name of the
# file minus the extension (like ".txt" or ".db").  There is normally
# no need to change the default.
# Multiple FontPath entries are allowed (they are concatenated together)
# By default, Red Hat 6.0 and later now use a font server independent of
# the X server to render fonts.
        RgbPath      "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/rgb"
        FontPath     "unix/:7100"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "dbe"
        Load  "extmod"
        Load  "fbdevhw"
        Load  "glx"
        Load  "record"
        Load  "freetype"
        Load  "type1"
        Load  "dri"
EndSection

# Section "InputDevice"
#
# # Specify which keyboard LEDs can be user-controlled (eg, with xset(1))
# #     Option  "Xleds"         "1 2 3"
# # To disable the XKEYBOARD extension, uncomment XkbDisable.
# #     Option  "XkbDisable"
# # To customise the XKB settings to suit your keyboard, modify the
# # lines below (which are the defaults).  For example, for a non-U.S.
# # keyboard, you will probably want to use:
# #     Option  "XkbModel"      "pc102"
# # If you have a US Microsoft Natural keyboard, you can use:
# #     Option  "XkbModel"      "microsoft"
# #
# # Then to change the language, change the Layout setting.
# # For example, a german layout can be obtained with:
# #     Option  "XkbLayout"     "de"
# # or:
# #     Option  "XkbLayout"     "de"
# #     Option  "XkbVariant"    "nodeadkeys"
# #
# # If you'd like to switch the positions of your capslock and
# # control keys, use:
# #     Option  "XkbOptions"    "ctrl:swapcaps"
# # Or if you just want both to be control, use:
# #     Option  "XkbOptions"    "ctrl:nocaps"
# #
#       Identifier  "Keyboard0"
#       Driver      "kbd"
#       Option      "XkbModel" "pc105"
#       Option      "XkbLayout" "us"
# EndSection

# Section "InputDevice"
#       Identifier  "Mouse0"
#       Driver      "mouse"
#       Option      "Protocol" "IMPS/2"
#       Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
#       Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
#       Option      "Emulate3Buttons" "yes"
# EndSection

# Section "Monitor"
#       Identifier   "Monitor0"
#       VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
#       ModelName    "Unknown monitor"
#       HorizSync    31.5 - 37.9
#       VertRefresh  50.0 - 70.0
#       Option      "dpms"
# EndSection

# Section "Device"
#       Identifier  "Videocard0"
#       Driver      "vesa"
#       VendorName  "Videocard vendor"
#       BoardName   "VESA driver (generic)"
# EndSection

# Section "Screen"
#       Identifier "Screen0"
#       Device     "Videocard0"
#       Monitor    "Monitor0"
#       DefaultDepth     24
#       SubSection "Display"
#               Viewport   0 0
#               Depth     16
#               Modes    "800x600" "640x480"
#       EndSubSection
#       SubSection "Display"
#               Viewport   0 0
#               Depth     24
#               Modes    "800x600" "640x480"
#       EndSubSection
# EndSection

Section "DRI"
        Group        0
        Mode         0666
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier   "Keyboard[0]"
  Driver       "kbd"
        Option      "XkbModel" "pc105"
        Option      "XkbLayout" "us"
  Option       "Protocol" "Standard"
  Option       "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
  Driver       "mouse"
  Identifier   "Mouse[1]"
  Option       "Buttons" "9"
  Option       "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
  Option       "Name" "VirtualBox Mouse Buttons"
  Option       "Protocol" "explorerps/2"
  Option       "Vendor" "Oracle Corporation"
  Option       "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
  Option       "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
  Driver       "vboxmouse"
  Identifier   "Mouse[2]"
  Option       "Device" "/dev/vboxguest"
  Option       "Name" "VirtualBox Mouse"
  Option       "Vendor" "Oracle Corporation"
  Option       "SendCoreEvents"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier   "Layout[all]"
  InputDevice  "Keyboard[0]" "CoreKeyboard"
  InputDevice  "Mouse[1]" "CorePointer"
  InputDevice  "Mouse[2]" "SendCoreEvents"
  Option       "Clone" "off"
  Option       "Xinerama" "off"
  Screen       "Screen[0]"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier   "Monitor[0]"
  ModelName    "VirtualBox Virtual Output"
  VendorName   "Oracle Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  BoardName    "VirtualBox Graphics"
  Driver       "vboxvideo"
  Identifier   "Device[0]"
  VendorName   "Oracle Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth      24
  EndSubSection
  Device       "Device[0]"
  Identifier   "Screen[0]"
  Monitor      "Monitor[0]"
EndSection


---------------------------------------------
```