# xrandr missing default screen resolution on kubuntu 16.04 for external video card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

I know I know, there are tons of questions regarding unrecognized screen resolutions, using `xrandr`, installing Nvidia drivers and related.

My new system is running Kubuntu 16.04, with kernel version 4.4.0-generic. It is a custom built computer, running an external video card, [EVGA 1060 GTX 3GB model](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=03G-P4-6160-KR).

Following advices in this "guide": [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/680826#680826) I was able to install the latest `nvidia-370`.

Now, on the ASUS monitor I am currently at ([ASUS VS247H](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Asus-VS247H-Widescreen-Monitor-50000000/dp/B0050Q5OTQ)), the resolution should be 1920x1080, but only a maximum of 1024x768 is shown if running `xrandr -q`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

Things I tried so far:

1)-------------------------------

The first thing that bothered me from the above was the line

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

I tried some things, for example the first answer of this question here: ["Fails to get size of gamma" error when trying to set resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94053/fails-to-get-size-of-gamma-error-when-trying-to-set-resolution), which did not have any effect.

Then I realized that I had no file under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` did not exist, and yet another answer at the site popped up: [/etc/X11/xorg.conf doesn't exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25746/etc-x11-xorg-conf-doesnt-exist?rq=1)

Fazit: I tried generating my own as described in the first answer of this question: [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there) and then manually set a `Screen` with the correct resolution, without success.

2)-------------------------------

As mentioned in [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr) about xrandr, I tried using

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
xrandr --newmode <output of the above>
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080_60.00
```

But still, the above

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

seems to be killing me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to identify "the ASUS monitor I am currently at" This information may be helpful in determining what the root cause of your problem might be. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow , nice graphics card !

its supported by the 367.27 which is supposed to be stable on day one according to phoronix.

```
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nv-linux-gtx1060&num=1
```

heres the nvidia driver ,

```
http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverresults.aspx/104284/en-us
```

but i'd recommend using the graphics-drivers-ppa version as it will be less fiddly to install and upgrade.

```
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
```

There instructions on how to install on that page.

Comment: Thanks man! Not sure why, but when it was asking me to disable the UEFI mode it was not working before. Now I am on the 1920x1080 that I should have been from the beginning ;-)

Comment: there are apparently some issues with secure mode booting and nvidia cards , secure mode is a feature of UEFI.  As i haven't found the actual cause i'm going to guess that its the requirement for secure boot to have a signed kernel images being difficult to statisfy with irregular binary driver releases that have specific distribution requirements.